# Is (reverse . f . reverse) efficient?

Tags: haskell

Many times I see functions which operate on the head of a list, e.g:

```
trimHead ('\n':xs) = xs
trimHead xs        = xs
```

then I see the the definition:

```
trimTail = reverse . trimHead . reverse
```

then I see:

```
trimBoth = trimHead . trimTail
```

They are clean, but are `trimTail` and `trimBoth` efficient? Is there a better way?

Comment: For clarification: Do you want to trim exactly one newline at the end or as many as possible? Your code hints the first one, but the second one seems also possible. My answer is for the second case, use hammar's for the first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider this alternative implementation

```
trimTail2 [] = []
trimTail2 ['\n'] = []
trimTail2 (x:xs) = x : trimTail2 xs

trimBoth2 = trimHead . trimTail2
```

It's easy to confirm that `trimTail` and `trimBoth` require that the entire list be evaluated, while `trimTail2` and `trimBoth2` only evaluate as much of the list as is necessary.

```
*Main> head $ trimTail ('h':undefined)
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
*Main> head $ trimBoth ('h':undefined)
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
*Main> head $ trimTail2 ('h':undefined)
'h'
*Main> head $ trimBoth2 ('h':undefined)
'h'
```

This implies that your version is going to be less efficient if the whole result is not needed.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't efficient in the sense, that streaming is impossible, because the whole list needs to be evaluated to get even a single element. But a better solution is difficult, as you need to evaluate the rest of the list to know, whether a line-break is to be trimmed or not. A slightly more efficient way would be to look ahead whether the linebreak is to be trimmed and react appropriately:

```
trimTail, trimHead, trimBoth :: String -> String
trimTail ('\n':xs) | all (=='\n') xs = ""
trimTail (x:xs)                      = x : trimTail xs

trimHead = dropWhile (=='\n')

trimBoth = trimTail . trimHead
```

The solution above evaluates only as much as needed from the string to know, if the linebreak is to be trimmed. An even better method would be to incorporate the knowledge, that the next *n* chars are not to be trimmed. Implementing this is left as an exercise to the reader.

An even better (and shorter) way to write `trimTail` is this way (by *rotsor*):

```
trimTail = foldr step [] where
  step '\n' [] = []
  step x xs = x:xs
```

Generally, try to avoid `reverse`. Usually there is a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: Well, that use of `all` is both cute and subtle. If you expect the text to have lots of `\n` characters in sequence in the middle, it's a bit bad (quadratic in the number of consecutive newlines) -- but that particular case seems unlikely, and fixing the problem should that case arise is pretty easy. Nice answer!

Comment: It's not exactly correct to call asymptotically slower algorithm "more efficient"! Here goes "a better method" btw: `trimTail = foldr step [] where step '\n' [] = []; step x xs = x:xs`

Comment: @Rotsor that's good. Can I incorporate this into my answer or do you want to open another answer.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the whole list is to be evaluated (if you don't need the whole list, why are you trimming the end?), it's about half as efficient as you can get out of immutable lists, but it has the same asymptotic complexity O(n).

The new list requires at least:

1. You have to find the end: n pointer traversals.
2. You have to modify the end, and thus what points to the end, etc.: n cons of existing data with new pointers.

`reverse . trimHead . reverse` performs roughly twice this:

1. The first `reverse` performs n pointer traversals and n cons.
2. `trimHead` possibly performs 1 pointer traversal.
3. The second `reverse` performs n pointer traversals and n cons.

Is this worth worrying about?  In some circumstances, maybe.  Is the code too slow, and is this called a lot?  In others, maybe not.  Benchmark!  The implementation with `reverse` is nice and easy to understand, and that's important.

There is a fairly natural recursive step-through-the-list solution, which will only evaluate as much of the output as is consumed, so in the case that you don't know whether you need the whole string, you can possibly save some evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

> Are trimHead and trimTail efficient?

They both take *O(n)* time (time directly proportional to the size of the list) since the entire list must be traversed twice in order to perform the two reverses.

> Is there a better way?

Well, do you have to use lists? With `Data.Sequence` you can modify either end of the list in constant time. If you're stuck with lists, then check out the other solutions suggested here. If you can use Sequences instead, then just modify FUZxxl's answer to use [`dropWhileR`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html#v%3adropWhileR).